# How to create global var $schema for connection to DB in Catalyst app?

Tags: perl, catalyst, dbix-class

I've created a model lib/MyApp/Model/Foo.pm. Inside it:

```
...
sub bar {
  my $schema = MyApp::Schem->connect("dbi:SQLite:data.db");
}
...
```

It works fine but when I write so:

```
...
my $schema = MyApp::Schema->connect("dbi:SQLite:data.db");
sub bar {}
...
```

it doesn't work and write this:

> Can't locate object method "connect" via package "MyApp::Schema"
>   (perhaps you forgot to load "MyApp::Schema"?) at ...

I'd like to create global $schema var to use it in different methods. How can I reach it?

Comment: Since you're using catalyst you could initialize the schema when the application starts using a singleton. Then it should be available throughout the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read in [Catalyst::Model::DBIC::Schema](http://search.cpan.org/~rkitover/Catalyst-Model-DBIC-Schema-0.60/lib/Catalyst/Model/DBIC/Schema.pm) that we can us $self->schema to get access to db schema from anywhere. So this variant works fine:

```
sub bar {
  my ($self) = @_;
  my $schema = $self->schema;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Catalyst::Model::DBIC::Schema](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aModel%3a%3aDBIC%3a%3aSchema) handles connecting to the database automatically for every process that might be started.

If you create your MyApp::Model::DBIC using the helper as shown in the synopsis it will work out-of-the-box. Database credentials or the database filename in case of SQLite are usually put inside the Catalyst config file loaded by [Catalyst::Plugin::ConfigLoader](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aConfigLoader).

Note that you normally don't add any methods to the Catalyst model nor the DBIx::Class schema.

To access the model, regardless of its type (DBIC, LDAP, ...), you have to use `$c->model($modelname)` in Catalyst. So if you named your model MyApp::Model::DBIC this would be `$c->model('DBIC')`.
To access a DBIC resultset you can either use `$c->model('DBIC')->resultset('Foo')` or `$c->model('DBIC::Foo')` which is a special syntax [Catalyst::Model::DBIC::Schema](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aModel%3a%3aDBIC%3a%3aSchema) supports.

Comment: `Note that you normally don't add any methods to the Catalyst model` oh, and where must I keep them?

Comment: Depends on what the methods should do. If they should be callable onto a DBIC $row object they go into the result class, if its a method for a resultset like for example a predefined search it goes into the resultset class of that table. Those are all DBIx::Class related things and have nothing to do if you use the DBIC model with Catalyst or something else.

Comment: Hah, thanks. I didn't know that methods for work with defined table may be kept in resultset class.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to load `MyApp::Schema`?

When you call `MyApp::Schema->connect` inside a subroutine, it is likely that some other Catalyst component has already loaded the `MyApp::Schema` module and made the `connect` method available.

Outside the subroutine, your application will try to call `MyApp::Schema::connect` at the time your `MyApp::Model::Foo` module is loaded, and whether it will succeed or not will depend on the order that other packages are loaded. So writing `use MyApp::Schema;` at the top of your `MyApp::Model::Foo` package might solve your problem.

---

Another thing that might solve your problem is lazy initialization of your schema. Replace all instances of `$schema` in your model with a function call, say, `schema()`, and include this code:

```
my $_schema;
sub schema {
    $_schema //= MyApp::Schem->connect("dbi:SQLite:data.db")
}
```

Now your schema object gets initialized once, when it's needed, and probably after all the other relevant modules your application depends on have been loaded.

Comment: Your answer doesn't make any sense because if the helper to generate the DBIC model is used the containing code will work out-of-the-box without any guessing. It takes care of loading the schema itself, there is no need to do that manually.